# C++ lookup for dependent names

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

In the current C++ standard (march 2019), there are these two paragraphs (emphasis mine):

[[temp.res] p.2](http://eel.is/c%2B%2Bdraft/temp.res#2):

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type **unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name** or the name is qualified by the keyword typename. [...]

[[temp.res] p.9](http://eel.is/c%2B%2Bdraft/temp.res#9):

> When looking for the declaration of a name used in a template definition, the usual lookup rules ([basic.lookup.unqual], [basic.lookup.argdep]) are used for non-dependent names. The lookup of names dependent on the template parameters is postponed until the actual template argument is known ([temp.dep]). [...]

The first paragraph implies that a name that is dependent on a template parameter will be looked up by "the applicable name lookup".

However, the second paragraph states that lookup for names dependent on template parameters is postponed until the template argument is known.

The example that is part of the first paragraph includes a situation similar to the following one:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    void f()
    {
        T* p;
    }
};
```

In method `f`, I believe `T` is a "name dependent on template parameters", therefore its lookup should be postponed until `T` is known, therefore there is no "applicable name lookup", the name should be assumed not to name a type.

What does the first quoted paragraph mean by "unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name", if the second quoted paragraph seems to state that there is no lookup performed? Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190426/discussion-on-question-by-user42768-c-lookup-for-dependent-names).

Answer (score 1):

The lookup that is postponed is for [*dependent names*](http://eel.is/c%2B%2Bdraft/temp.dep#2): for example, `foo` in contexts like `T::foo` or `Bar<T>::foo`, or `operator@` in contexts like `T() @ 0`.  Obviously `T` and `Bar` must themselves be looked up just to know a template parameter is involved (template parameters [can be hidden](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.local#7)) and to parse the template argument list.  Since a (type) template parameter is a [*typedef-name*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#3) and any specialization of `Bar` is a type, that “name lookup finds a type name”.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One thing that is, in my opinion, ambiguous is the use of the two constructs: "dependent name" (which is defined in the first paragraph you linked) and "name dependent on a template parameter" (which is not defined explicitly). Paragraph 9 uses the latter wording. According to the definition of "dependent name", A<T> (where A is a class template and T is a template parameter) is not a "dependent name". What happens if that template is specialized after it is referred to? [continued]

Comment: Are only specializations declared before the use considered, or are all specializations declared before the point of instantiation used? Paragraph 9 says that lookup is postponed, but is it specified elsewhere what locations are searched?

Comment: Also, I think paragraph 2 should be reworded as: "A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless it can be determined to be a type name (this process may include name lookup of non-dependent parts of the name) or the name is qualified by the keyword typename. [...]". Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: @user42768: The longer formulation is [identified](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#1.2) with the shorter.  `A<T>` is not a dependent *name* but a [dependent *type*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#temp.dep.type-9).  Specializations are consulted when the referencing template is [instantiated](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst).  Dependent *names* are looked up in the [instantiation context](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.candidate#1).  I’m sure [temp.res]/2 can be improved, but we can probably do better than “it’s not a type unless we know it is”.

Comment: @user42768: I should say that your proposed rewording looks “correct” in that I think you understand the rule; it’s not *quite* right because of things like looking up names that turn out to be template parameters (which is certainly dependent—after the lookup).

Comment: I agree that dependent names still must be searched in order to determine that they are in fact "dependent" (T needs to be searched in order for the compiler to know it is a template parameter).

Comment: So you're saying that "name dependent on a template parameter" = "dependent name" = "unqualified function call with "dependent" arguments" (my simplified (and probably incomplete) definition of [temp.dep p.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#temp.dep-2)). But then the second sentence of paragraph 9 (The lookup of names dependent on the template parameters is postponed until the actual template argument is known ([temp.dep])) does not apply to `A<T>` because it is not a name dependent on the template parameters ( = dependent name). What am I missing?

Comment: So if the name lookup for `A<T>` is not postponed, why are template specializations in the context of the point of instantiation found?

Comment: Or did you want to say that "dependent name" = "name dependent on a template parameter" and that the definition in [temo.dep p.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#temp.dep-2) describes just one type of "dependent names"? Based on that fact that you said that `A<T>` is not a dependent name, I think you did not mean this.

Comment: @user42768: As `A<T>` is not a name at all, it is not a dependent name, nor is it *ever* subject to *name lookup*.  Specializations are [not found via name lookup](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.spec#7), but are selected by the “instantiation” process (scare quotes because it might find an explicit specialization instead of instantiating anything).

Comment: @user42768: Technically, a *template-id* [is a “name”](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#4), but it is used as such only for declaration purposes, not lookup.

Comment: Ok, so `A<T>` is not a dependent name. Therefore its name lookup is not postponed. And the paragraph you quoted (regarding specializations), says the following: "Rather, when the primary template name is used, any previously-declared partial specializations of the primary template are also considered.". So if I read this literally, in the template definition, the primary template name is used, therefore only "previously-declared partial specializations of the primary template are also considered", right?

Comment: @user42768: When one template is named in another’s definition, the “use” occurs only when the latter template is instantiated; only then does a specialization need to be chosen.  (It’s also possible to name templates like `B<T>::template C<T>`, where *which template* is in use is determined only at instantiation.)

Comment: I agree that logically the name should be considered "used" only inside a specialization. However, does the standard explicitly say this? Although I realise that maybe this clarification isn't really needed.

Comment: As you said, `A<T>` is not a "dependent name", therefore its name lookup is not postponed. So a declaration (of the primary template) must be found at definition time. So even if I know for sure what template I am referring to, it is still considered not used in the definition?

Comment: @user42768: Unfortunately, the actual process of template instantiation is never really specified; this is a [very long-standing issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2).  You do know the *template* (except when `::template` must be used) but not what *unknown specialization* is being used (the word “unknown” referring to the possibility of a specialization declared after the definition of a client template but before its instantiation).

Comment: Ok. So even though it is not explicitly specified in the standard, I agree that a template is "used" only inside a specialization of a template.

Comment: Regarding the concepts of "dependent name" and "name that depends on a template parameter", in [temp.dep p.3](http://eel.is/c%2B%2Bdraft/temp.res#temp.dep-3) it says that "The base class name B<T>, the type name T::A, the names B<T>::i and pb->j explicitly depend on the template-parameter". So `B<T>` is not a dependent name, but it depends on a template parameter.

Comment: @user42768: Yes (although a **call** like `f<T>()` makes `f<T>` a dependent name); that example should be moved before /2 (which was only in this draft separated from /1).

Comment: What I was trying to say is that the standard treats "dependent name" and "name that depends on a type parameter" differently in temp.dep p.3. "Dependent names" appears to be a subset of "names that depend on a template parameter", at least based on this paragraph.

Comment: So, at least in [temp.dep] p.3, "dependent name" != "name that depends on a template parameter". Or am I misinterpreting something again?

Comment: @user42768: Sure—I think the example is (as is common for non-normative text) using the word “name” very loosely, since of course `pb->j` is not a (single) name.

Comment: Ok, so finally, "name dependent on a template parameter" = "dependent name" = definition in [temp.dep] p.2 (unqualified names used as the postfix expression in function calls and operators, under certain conditions). Although in the discussion under my question @LanguageLawyer mentioned a defect report that states that T::x should also be a dependent name.